# Non-Azure input/source options for Steam Analytics

Tags: node.js, azure, cortana-intelligence, azure-stream-analytics

Does Steam Analytics support input sources other than products in the Azure family?

For example, can I setup a REST endpoint and send events this way?  Are there client libraries for node.js?

Documentation is somewhat scant in this regard; I wanted to check here before assuming **no** on both fronts.

Comment: Of course it does, through Event Hubs, its main ingestion option. Stream Analytics *processes* the events, it doesn't *ingest* them. Event hub provides REST, AMQP, MQTT endpoints, batching, partitioning etc. Event Hub is built to handle millions of events and Stream Analytics to process them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Some circumstantial evidence below seems to prove that Azure not suppport non Azure Service as input for Stream Analytics.

1. From the REST API `Create Input` of Stream Analytics https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835010.aspx, there are only three data sources that include `Event Hub`, `Blob Storgae` & `IoT Hub`.
2. Screenshots from Azure old & new portal for add input.

Fig 1. The input options on Azure old portal (Step 1)
[image]

Fig 2. The options for Data stream (Step 2)
[image]

Fig 3. The option for Reference data (Step 2)
[image]

Fig 4. The input options on Azure new portal
[image]

Comment: This doesn't prove anything other than a misunderstanding of Stream Analytics. This is the *processing* service, not the ingestion endpoint. Would you say that SQL Server doesn't accept connections from outside SQL Server because the *query processor* only accepts calls from the network subsystem? Or would you say that it's the network subsystem's role to accept such connections?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos According to the offical docs include the description of REST APIs, I don't see there are any other connections as input source. Could you explain how to use the other connections like SQL Server as input source? Thanks for your sharing.

Comment: What other connections? ASA is a *processing* service, not an ingestion service. In fact, it doesn't support *any* input except Event Hub and blob, because it *doesn't* make any sense to do so.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT Would you mind reaching to me internally? My alias is pakefali. The above answer should be revised to include more information and limitations as it's not 100% correct the way it is now. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no Azure Stream Analytics does not currently support non Azure sources.

One recommended approach is to write to Azure Event Hub then let Azure Stream Analytics read from there.

You could write to an event hub in Node.JS:
http://hypernephelist.com/2014/09/16/sending-data-to-azure-event-hubs-from-nodejs.html

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: This is not correct, due to a misconception of what Stream Analytics is/does. It *processes* external events. It doesn't *ingest* them, that's the job of Event Hub. Ingesting millions of events is *not* trivial, which is why the two services are separate

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Agreed. You call it "ingest" and the questioner called it "source". Regardless ASA processes events that are already in Azure and can't process events that are ingested by some service that's not in Azure. Why the down vote?

Comment: Because these are completely different concepts, and the conclusion is wrong. Event Hub isn't the source, it's the endpoint that accepts the data from the sources and passes them to the analytics service. If Azure was a database, Event Hub would be the the RPC subsystem that listens for ODBC, OLEDB connections and Stream Analytics would be the query processor.

Answer (score 0):

**Revise for my old answer.**

As @PanagiotisKanavos said, Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) is just the processing service engine, not the ingestion endpoint, that doesn't need to have a non-azure input source as EventHub do and that how to feed ASA with data to it.

EventHub can be used by ASA, has a variety of libraries that work on tons of different machines, form factors etc, and can run on any OS and many frameworks. Worst case, simple HTTP works as well, AMQP is not mandatory but definitely ideal in terms of performance.

The correct route is `PRODUCER -> EventHub -> ASA` or `PRODUCER -> STORAGE -> ASA`. So if there is a library that supports storage on the device that they want, it can work as well, but EventHub is obviously a better choice.

Thanks a lot for @PanagiotisKanavos help.